# Simplify excel function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

IF(SUMIFS('SAP TRACKER'!N:N,'SAP TRACKER'!K:K,[@FPC],'SAP TRACKER'!B:B,"Shipped",'SAP TRACKER'!J:J,[@PO])-IF(ROW(F40)=3,0,SUMIFS($N$3:N39,$F$3:F39,F40,$D$3:D39,D40))>[@[QTY (IT)]],[@[QTY (IT)]],SUMIFS('SAP TRACKER'!N:N,'SAP TRACKER'!K:K,[@FPC],'SAP TRACKER'!B:B,"Shipped",'SAP TRACKER'!J:J,[@PO])-IF(ROW(F40)=3,0,SUMIFS($N$3:N39,$F$3:F39,F40,$D$3:D39,D40)))

this function returnes the sum of shipped quantity of a certain Material in a certain PO, i have 2 more functions in consqunt columns to return inprogrees shipments, but the workbook is heavy and keeps clacluating 8 threads every time i do something, i have turned off automaic saving, is there a simpler function to give same result
Sap tracker "the sheet that i input shipments"
'SAP TRACKER'!N:N: "quantity of the material being shipped"
'SAP TRACKER'!K:K "first criteria material number"
[@FPC] "the material number in the sheet i have the function in"
'SAP TRACKER'!B:B "the status shipped, inprogress"
'SAP TRACKER'!J:J "second criteria PO number"
[@PO] "PO In the sheet i have the function"

Comment: The problem is likely in the whole column reference, but without any dummy data we can't reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, don't compute things twice. Basically, your formula is

```
IF(
 CompareComplicatedValueAndSomeOtherValue,
 SomeOtherValue,
 ComplicatedValue
)
```

... where you are deriving the complicated value twice.

You could use `LET`, but in this case you're just taking the minimum of `SomeOtherValue` and `ComplicatedValue` so it's better to just use `MIN` like so...

```
MIN(
 SUMIFS(
  'SAP TRACKER'!N:N,
  'SAP TRACKER'!K:K,
  [@FPC],
  'SAP TRACKER'!B:B,
  "Shipped",
  'SAP TRACKER'!J:J,
  [@PO]
 )-IF(
  ROW(F40)=3,
  0,
  SUMIFS(
   $N$3:N39,
   $F$3:F39,
   F40,
   $D$3:D39,
   D40
  )
 ),
 [@[QTY (IT)]]
)
```

Another issue I see is that you are mixing "normal" cell references with table cell references. If you use `ROW()` and `OFFSET()` you can refer to all cells in your table by table reference, even "everything in a column above a particular row". Done this way, Excel can store one formula per column, instead of one formula per cell. I have no idea if this has performance benefits, but it will sure help you whenever you need to fix anything because you won't have to drag your formula change all the way down the table anymore.

Another thing you could consider is, when computing running totals, instead of doing sumifs, figure out the immediately preceding subtotal already calculated and add the current row to it. Those SUMIFS you are using get geometrically more expensive the more rows you have in a table. Cheating by finding the last-calculated value and adding to it will likely be more performant. That said, I don't know your data well. You didn't really provide a lot to go on. I don't think I can help you more than theoretically on this one.